# creating relationships via full text search in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search, cypher

I built a Neo4j graph database containing about 50 000 nodes with the label DIAGNOSE, each having a string property TEXT with up to 50 characters. The same graph database contains about 120 000 nodes with the label BASETEXT, each having a string property TEXTVALUE with up to 175 000 characters. My goal is to create a relationship (b:BASETEXT) –[:ASSOCIATED]-> (d:DIAGNOSE) in case DIAGNOSE.TEXT is included in BASETEXT.TEXTVALUE – resulting in a total of about 2.9 * 10^9 searches. I tried the following two approaches in cypher:

Approach 1:

```
match (b:BASETEXT), (d:DIAGNOSE)
where b.TEXTVALUE =~ (".* " + d.TEXT + " .*")
merge (b) -[:ASSOCIATED]-> (d);
```

Approach 2 (create a relationship between every DIAGNOSE node and every BASETEXT node, if TEXT is in TEXTVALUE assign value true to relationship property CONTAINED, otherwise value false, finally delete all relationships with ASSOCIATED.CONTAINED = false):

```
match (b:BASETEXT), (d:DIAGNOSE)
where not (b) -[:ASSOCIATED]-> (d)
with b, d limit 20000
create (b) -[a:ASSOCIATED]-> (d)
with b, d, a
set a.CONTAINED =
case
when (b.TEXTVALUE =~ (".* " + d.TEXT + " .*")) then true
else false
end 
return count(a);
```

None of the approaches mentioned above works. Approach 1 doesn’t find an end within half an hour, approach 2 finds an end but would take me 60 days.
Any suggestions how to properly implement text search in Neo4J and to solve the problem – preferably in Cypher?

Comment: Don't use regex but use the Lucene legacy indexes for full text searches:see eg. http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

Comment: there has been a webinar on document classification recorded at http://player.vimeo.com/video/105266385. I guess this is somehow similar to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I also created a [graph-gist for it, for illustration](http://gist.neo4j.org/?6b4ce0013c8f2b1ec506).

I think that's a use-case that's not well supported in cypher yet.

If you want to try a simple cypher variant that should work (but slowly) try this:

```
MATCH (d:DIAGNOSE)
WHERE NOT () -[:ASSOCIATED]-> (d)
WITH d 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 1000
MATCH (b:BASETEXT)
WHERE (b.TEXTVALUE =~ (".* " + d.TEXT + " .*"))
CREATE (b) -[:ASSOCIATED]-> (d)
RETURN count(*);
```

It should be much faster to do in Java:

```
public class ConnectIndexTest {
    private static final String PATH = "target/connect.db";
    public static final Label BASETEXT = DynamicLabel.label("BASETEXT");
    public static final Label DIAGNOSE = DynamicLabel.label("DIAGNOSE");
    public static final String TEXTVALUE = "TEXTVALUE";
    public static final String TEXT = "TEXT";
    public static final String INDEX_NAME = "basetext";
    private static final RelationshipType ASSOCIATED = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("ASSOCIATED");
    private GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
//      db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(PATH);
        db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            for (int i = 100_000; i < 250_000; i++) db.createNode(BASETEXT).setProperty(TEXTVALUE, "foo " + i + " bar");
            tx.success();
        }
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            for (int i = 100_000; i < 250_000; i += 2) db.createNode(DIAGNOSE).setProperty(TEXT, String.valueOf(i));
            tx.success();
        }
    }

    // 120k BASETEXT Nodes
    // 50k DIAGNOSE Nodes
    @Test
    public void testConnect() throws Exception {
        GlobalGraphOperations ops = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db);
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> index = db.index().forNodes(INDEX_NAME, LuceneIndexImplementation.FULLTEXT_CONFIG);
            for (Node baseText : ops.getAllNodesWithLabel(BASETEXT)) {
                index.add(baseText, TEXTVALUE, baseText.getProperty(TEXTVALUE));
            }
            tx.success();
        }
        int count = 0;
        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        try {
            Index<Node> index = db.index().forNodes(INDEX_NAME);
            for (Node diagnose : ops.getAllNodesWithLabel(DIAGNOSE)) {
                String text = (String) diagnose.getProperty(TEXT);
                IndexHits<Node> hits = index.query(TEXTVALUE, "\"" + text + "\"");// quote in case text contains spaces
                for (Node baseText : hits) {
                    baseText.createRelationshipTo(diagnose, ASSOCIATED);
                    // batch transaction
                    if (++count % 50000 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("count = " + count);
                        tx.success();
                        tx.close();
                        tx = db.beginTx();
                    }
                }
            }

            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.close();
        }
        System.out.println("count = " + count);
    }
}
```